# Cassandra - Connection and Data Insertion

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

### Below is my basic program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Cluster cluster;
  Session session;

  cluster  = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.20.131").withPort(9042).build();

  System.out.println("Connection Established");

  cluster.close();
}
```

---

Now i want to know that i have a 7 node cluster and i have cassandra instance running on all 7 nodes. Assuming that the above mentioned IP address is my entry point how does it actually works. Suppose some other user try to run a program on any other cassandra node out of 7 so which IP will be entered as Contact Point. Or do i have to add all the 7 nodes IP addresses comma separated in my main() method ..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cassandra Java driver: how many contact points is reasonable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852413/cassandra-java-driver-how-many-contact-points-is-reasonable)

Answer (score 0):

As it is described [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/common/drivers/reference/nodeDiscovery_r.html),

> The driver discovers the nodes that constitute a cluster by querying
>   the contact points used in building the cluster object. After this it
>   is up to the cluster's load balancing policy to keep track of node
>   events (that is add, down, remove, or up) by its implementation of the
>   Host.StateListener interface.